# how to run oracle stored procedure in php

Tags: php, oracle

I have tried the following

```
class DatabaseConnection {


    private $con;
        private $credentials;
        protected $statement;
        private $dbName;
        // parsedSQL is not intended to used by anything except logging in the case of failed execution.
        public $parsedSql;
        protected $mode = OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS;
        const OCI_RETURN_DB_POINTER = 1001;
        const OCI_RETURN_DB_PERSISTENT = 1002;
        const OCI_RETURN_DB_UNIQUE = 1003;

    public function __construct($dbName, $connectType = DatabaseConnection::OCI_RETURN_DB_POINTER) {
            $this->credentials = array (
                    "slrukdb" => array (
                            "username" => "OBLICORE",
                            "pw" => "xxx",
                            "connstr" => "OIUKDB.prod.uk" 
                    ),
            );
            $dbName = strtolower ( $dbName );
            $this->dbName = $dbName;
            switch ($connectType) {
                case DatabaseConnection::OCI_RETURN_DB_POINTER :
                    $this->con = oci_connect ( $this->credentials [$dbName] ['username'], $this->credentials [$dbName] ['pw'], $this->credentials [$dbName] ['connstr'] );
                    break;
                case DatabaseConnection::OCI_RETURN_DB_PERSISTENT :
                    $this->con = oci_pconnect ( $this->credentials [$dbName] ['username'], $this->credentials [$dbName] ['pw'], $this->credentials [$dbName] ['connstr'] );
                    break;
                case DatabaseConnection::OCI_RETURN_DB_UNIQUE :
                    $this->con = oci_new_connect ( $this->credentials [$dbName] ['username'], $this->credentials [$dbName] ['pw'], $this->credentials [$dbName] ['connstr'] );
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "No Connection";
                    die();
                    break;
            }

            if ($this->dbName == 'slrukdb') {
                $dbt = debug_backtrace ();
                $location = substr ( strrchr ( $dbt [0] ["file"], "/" ), 1 ) . " (" . $dbt [0] ["line"] . ")";
                oci_set_client_identifier ( $this->con, $location );
            }
        }   

public function execute($sql = null) {
        if ($this->dbName == 'slrukdb') {
            $dbt = debug_backtrace ();
            $location = substr ( strrchr ( $dbt [0] ["file"], "/" ), 1 ) . " (" . $dbt [0] ["line"] . ")";
            //print_r($this->con);
            //print_r($location);
            oci_set_client_identifier ( $this->con, $location );
        }
        if (! is_null ( $sql )) {
            $ocistatement = oci_parse ( $this->con, $sql );
        } else {
            $ocistatement = $this->statement;
        }

        $success = oci_execute ( $ocistatement, $this->mode );
        if (! $success) {
            if ($this->mode != OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS) {
                $this->transactionRollback ();

                $exceptionSql = (is_null ( $sql )) ? $this->parsedSql : $sql;

                throw new Exception ( "Statement execution failed. Transaction rolled back. SQL: $exceptionSql" );
            } else {
                $message = "";
                $oci_error = oci_error ();
                if (! empty ( $oci_error )) {
                    $message = "OCI_ERROR: " . $oci_error ["code"] . ": " . $oci_error ["message"];
                    if (! empty ( $oci_error ["sqltext"] )) {
                        $message .= " in SQL{" . $oci_error ["sqltext"] . "}";
                    }
                } else {
                    $message = "unknown error in DatabaseConnection->execute";

                    if (! empty ( $this->parsedSql )) {
                        $message .= " with parsed SQL{" . $this->parsedSql . "}";
                    } else if (! empty ( $sql )) {
                        $message .= " with SQL{" . $sql . "}";
                    }
                }

                trigger_error ( $message, E_USER_ERROR );
            }
        }

        return $ocistatement;
    }
    }

$db = new DatabaseConnection ( 'slrukdb' );
$db->execute ( "P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency" );
```

I get error

```
PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement in /var/SP/oiadm/docroot/common/php/DatabaseConnection.php on line 170
PHP Fatal error:  unknown error in DatabaseConnection->execute with SQL{P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency} in /var/SP/oiadm/docroot/common/php/DatabaseConnection.php on line 196
```

procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE          P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency as

BEGIN

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'A','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_A_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'A','Cell',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_A_Interface where Cell is not null and Cell >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'A','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_A_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'A','PNUM',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_A_Interface where PNUM is not null and PNUM >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuCS','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuCS_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuCS','Cell',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuCS_Interface where Cell is not null and Cell >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuCS','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuCS_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuCS','PNUM',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuCS_Interface where PNUM is not null and PNUM >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'Gb','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_Gb_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'Gb','Cell',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_Gb_Interface where Cell is not null and Cell >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'Gb','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_Gb_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'Gb','APN',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_Gb_Interface where APN is not null and APN >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuPS','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuPS_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuPS','Cell',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuPS_Interface where Cell is not null and Cell >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuPS','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuPS_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'IuPS','APN',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_IuPS_Interface where APN is not null and APN >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN2G','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN2G_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN2G','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN2G_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN2G','APN',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN2G_Interface where APN is not null and APN >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN2G','PURL',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN2G_Interface where PURL is not null and PURL >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN2G','DOM',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN2G_Interface where DOM is not null and DOM >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN3G','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN3G_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN3G','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN3G_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN3G','APN',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN3G_Interface where APN is not null and APN >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN3G','PURL',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN3G_Interface where PURL is not null and PURL >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'GN3G','DOM',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_GN3G_Interface where DOM is not null and DOM >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'AllVoice','IMSI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_AllVoice_Interface where IMSI is not null and IMSI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'AllVoice','IMEI',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_AllVoice_Interface where IMEI is not null and IMEI >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'AllVoice','PNUM',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_AllVoice_Interface where PNUM is not null and PNUM >= 1000));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'BO','webi',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_BOTimestamps where Type = 'webi'));

insert into B_NMS_Interface_Latency values (sysdate,'BO','deski',(Select max(timestamp) from B_NMS_BOTimestamps where Type = 'deski'));

commit;

END P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency;
```

**UPDATE**

when i tried

```
 $db->execute ( "call P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency()" );
```

error:

```
PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "OBLICORE.P_B_NMS_INTERFACE_LATENCY", line 5 in /var/SP/oiadm/docroot/common/php/DatabaseConnection.php on line 170
PHP Fatal error:  unknown error in DatabaseConnection->execute with SQL{call P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency()} in /var/SP/oiadm/docroot/common/php/DatabaseConnection.php on line 196
```

Comment: so what's your `$sql` that's causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a procedure inside a BEGIN..END anonymous block like this

```
$sql = 'BEGIN P_B_NMS_Interface_Latency(); END;';

$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);

oci_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: What version of oracle are you using

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed the semicolon?